# Excel Index Match organize data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am having this issue where I am trying to match values from between two unorganized tables, I want the number (B column) next to the matching value (C column and M column) to appear on the approprate K column.
I used to do this in the past but something isn't piecing in together. Currently using this forumla

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$23,MATCH($M$3:$M$23,$C$3:$C$23,0))
```

But it keeps matching the first value (21718) over and over and not matching between the two.

[image: Excel Table here]

Comment: Are you using `arrayFormula`? If not, change the first parameter of `match()` to `$m3`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Match()` formula should be with a single first argument.
Like this:

`=MATCH($M$3,$C$3:$C$23,0)`

[Match Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$23,MATCH($M3,$C$3:$C$23,0),1)`

Drag this formula till end.